# meteorjs help navybits:pagination

Tags: meteor, pagination

`navybits:pagination` is a very good package to paginate data from personalized queries to the collection, I would like to use it in my projects, but i have 2 problems:

How can you increase the number of documents per page, by default it shows only 5?

How can you change the quantity and customize the nav- pagination buttons, by default it only shows 3 to 5, plus previous and next ??

I commented on the blog, but I have not had an answer.

If someone knows some other package to paginate data, in which I can make a personalized query to the collection, and then I can paginate an array of objects, let me know.
Thank you

Article: https://blog.navybits.com/efficient-and-high-performance-pagination-in-meteor-bb5d379d234

Demo: https://meteor.navybits.com/comments

Github: https://github.com/Navybits/meteor-pagination

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using this package, I solve it overwriting the function onCreated for "navybitsPagination" template.

```
Template.navybitsPagination.onCreated(function() {
```

You need to change this line...

```
 //setting the amount of data we want to render in each page
this.perPage = new ReactiveVar(Number(self.data.perPage) || 10);
```

You should find all the code on the Github repo of the package.
I hope it helps you.